# Prove or disprove the statement: For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, if $A=B \cup C$ then $A-B=C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to do this.
Please explain why its true or false.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: What if $A  = B = C$ is your very favorite set?

Comment: If only my favorite set wasn't empty... :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: try to draw some Venn Diagrams to grasp the intuition.